# Is Stack Overflow search not working?

Tags: support

Searching Stack Overflow for:

```
HttpResponseProxy 407 Proxy Authentication Required
```

[yields nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=HttpResponseProxy+407+Proxy+Authentication+Required),

[But searching the same on Google?](https://www.google.com/search?q=HttpResponseProxy+407+Proxy+Authentication+Required+site%3Astackoverflow.com&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS872US872&oq=HttpResponseProxy+407+Proxy+Authentication+Required+site%3Astackoverflow.com&aqs=chrome..69i57.7615j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Gives 48 results.

Please tell me if I am using the Stack Overflow search wrong.

Comment: Partially because SO's search is not intelligent enough to realize that one searching for "HttpResponseProxy" may be wishing to find matches for the phrase "Http Response Proxy" or something similar. Not sure if SO can even search for multiple words as a phrase...

Comment: The duplicate has been found by using the SO internal search function :D

Comment: Yes, you're using the search wrong. But I don't think you're guilty, though. The problem is that the internal search is notoriously bad. Yes, you *can* get what you need, provided you already know what you need. In your case you tried "HttpResponseProxy 407 Proxy Authentication Required" but that was wrong because there is no post that contains *all* of these at once. I really dislike this, for the record. It's especially bad when you want to try to find "sort" and it fails because the actual word in the post is "sort**ing**" or "sort**ed**"

Comment: I rarely use SO's search unless I'm looking for a specific post that I know its title or when using [search operators](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) (e.g., `user:xxxxx`, `is:answer`, `infavorites`, etc.). In almost any other situation, Google (or similar) is much much better. Use `searchQuery site:stackoverflow.com` in Google to get results only from SO.

Comment: Yes, since forever:((